# How to overlay a bigger boxplot across a discrete x-axis on top a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I can use ggplot2 to generate such a plot but it is a bit confusing because the bigger box does not cover the whole range of x and people interpreted it as excluding the first and the last sets of data. The geom_boxplot does not respond to the `width=` argument when used together with `aes(group=1)`. An example is given below.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p +geom_boxplot()+geom_boxplot(aes(group=1),width=0.1,col="red",fill=NA)
```

[image]

I have also opened an issue in the [ggplot2 github repository](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a numeric `x` value instead, without grouping:

```
nlevels <- length(unique(mpg$class))

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = median(1:nlevels)), width = nlevels, col = "red", fill = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a very clean and easy solution, I was thinking editing the data behind ggplot to adjust the width but did not succeed.